# How to get words average length using Lambda Expression

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have a word list text file, I want to get min, max and average word lengths from that file.

I have a stream method:

```
public static Stream<String> readWords(String filename) {
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
        Stream<String> stringStream = reader.lines();
        return stringStream;
    } catch (IOException exn) {
        return Stream.<String>empty();
    }
}
```

In my main method for testing I'm printing max and min

```
System.out.println(readWords(filename)
        .min(Comparator.comparing(s -> s.length()))
        .get()
        .length()
);
System.out.println(readWords(filename)
        .max(Comparator.comparing(s -> s.length()))
        .get()
        .length()
);
```

it works as expected.

**Questions:** 
Is it possible to get the average of the word length like I did in min and max? In both case yes or no, how to do that (only as Lambda Expression)?

Comment: you can use .reduce(0, (i, c) -> c+i.length()) and divide it by amount of lines.

Comment: hint: if your file is realy big and has lots of lines use collect instead of reduce

Comment: @JoshuaK thank you as well for your contribution, I found the answer below

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `lines()` method will get you a stream of the lines, not the words. Once you have the `Stream`, call [`flatMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) to replace the lines with the words, supplying the lambda expression to split out the words:

```
Stream<String> stringStream = reader.lines().flatMap( line -> 
    Stream.of(line.split("\\s+"))
);
```

This will correct your implementation of `max` and `min`. It also affects the correctness of any average calculation you wish to implement.

To obtain the average, you can call [`mapToInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#mapToInt-java.util.function.ToIntFunction-) to map the stream of words to their lengths (yielding an `IntStream`), then call [`average`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#average--), which returns an `OptionalDouble`.

```
System.out.println(readWords(filename)
    .mapToInt( s -> s.length() )  // or .mapToInt(String::length)
    .average()
    .getAsDouble());
```

Comment: It works thump up, and I like your input regarding .flatMap etc.

Comment: how about `summaryStatistics()` - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#summaryStatistics--

Comment: @bayou.io Yes, `summaryStatistics()` will work.  It will return an `IntSummaryStatistics` that gives the average and more: count, sum, min, and max.

Comment: Don’t create a temporary array for the words of a line. Use `flatMap(Pattern.compile("\\s+")::splitAsStream)`. And you don’t need to deal with `BufferedReader` manually. See [`Files.lines()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines-java.nio.file.Path-)

Comment: @Holger sound interesting I will try that.

Answer (score 7):

Use [`IntSummaryStatistics`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/IntSummaryStatistics.html) to get the min, max and average in one pass.

```
IntSummaryStatistics summary = readWords(filename)
    .collect(Collectors.summarizingInt(String::length));
System.out.format("min = %d, max = %d, average = %.2f%n",
    summary.getMin(), summary.getMax(), summary.getAverage());
```

Answer (score 6):

Based on official documentation about [reductions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/reduction.html)

```
System.out.println(readWords(filename)
                .mapToInt(String::length)
                .average()
                .getAsDouble()
);
```

Note that you can and probably should use method references like `String::length`

Comment: your code works too thump up I selected the other answer because of Stream input, your answer is valid as well.