# Finding max, min, sum, and average of n amount of values using for loop

Tags: java

Use the for loop to write a program to prompt the user to enter twelve n amount of numbers and then display the minimum, maximum, sum and the average of these numbers.

I don't can't puzzle how I would use a for loop in order to this, I've been having a bit of trouble.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Loop{

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter number 1: ");
        double a = scanner.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Enter number 2: ");
        double b = scanner.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Enter number 3: ");
        double c = scanner.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Enter number 4: ");
        double d = scanner.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Enter number 5: ");
        double e = scanner.nextDouble();    

        System.out.println("Enter number 6: ");
        double f = scanner.nextDouble();    

        System.out.println("Enter number 7: ");
        double g = scanner.nextDouble();    

        System.out.println("Enter number 8: ");
        double h = scanner.nextDouble();    

        System.out.println("Enter number 9: ");
        double i = scanner.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Enter number 10: ");
        double j = scanner.nextDouble();    

        System.out.println("Enter number 11: ");
        double k = scanner.nextDouble();    

        System.out.println("Enter number 12: ");
        double l = scanner.nextDouble();    

        double minNum = Math.min(a, Math.min(b, Math.min(c, Math.min(d, Math.min(e, Math.min(f, Math.min(g, Math.min(h, Math.min(i , Math.min(j, Math.min(k, l)))))))))));
        double maxNum = Math.max(a, Math.max(b, Math.max(c, Math.max(d, Math.max(e, Math.max(f, Math.max(g, Math.max(h, Math.max(i , Math.max(j, Math.max(k, l)))))))))));
        double sumNum = (a + b + c + d + e + f + g + h + i + j + k + l);

        for(int i = 0; )


    }

}
```

I expected the output to be used with the for loop, but then again I do not understand how I would use it in this method.

Comment: Let start with a for loop to print 1 to 12

Comment: Declare min and max first, the use a for each loop to do comparisons...

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32533555/how-to-get-words-average-length-using-lambda-expression

Comment: You need a tutorial on loops.

Comment: What's your exact problem? You dunno how to write a loop? Or you have wrote a loop but does not work? Be specific on your question.  StackOverflow is not a place for you to throw out your assignment and expect someone to finish it for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a nicer way to do this, which doesn't even require storing all the numbers at once.  The approach here is to keep a running tab on the largest and smallest input, as each new number is input.  Also, we maintain a running total of all numbers entered, which later easily can be used to compute the average.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
double max, min, avg;
double total = 0.0d;
boolean first = true;
int numbers = 12;

for (int i=0; i < numbers; ++i) {
    System.out.println("Enter number:");
    double d = scanner.nextDouble();

    if (first) {
        max = d;
        min = d;
        total = d;
        first = false;
    }
    else {
        if (d > max) {
            max = d;
        }
        else if (d < min) {
            min = d;
        }
        total += d;
    }
}

avg = total / numbers;
System.out.println("max: " + max + ", min: " + min + ", avg: " + avg);
```

Note that a more advanced approach might be to do something like store all 12 numbers into a list, and then leverage the Java 8 stream API to find the max, min, and average.  But I suspect that is not the answer you want for your question.

Comment: @Thilo Wow hard to believe that :-) ... agree about using an array (or maybe a list), but the approach I gave above completely avoids storage.  Maybe it meets the OP's expectations, or at least it could be helpful to someone else.

Comment: I think we can all agree on that this serves as a tutorial on loops. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Place this java code in the main function

```
`Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
int t=s.nextInt(); //12
int sum=0;
int min=Integer.MIN_VALUE;
int max=Integer.MAX_VALUE;
for(int i=0;i<t;i++){
int temp=s.nextInt();
if(temp<min)
 min=temp;
if(temp>max)
 max=temp;
sum+=temp;
}
System.out.println(min +" "+max+" "+sum);`
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
double max = Double.MAX_VALUE, min = Double.MIN_VALUE, total = 0.00d;
int n = 12; // Change this to the number of values needed
for (int i=0; i < n; i++) {
    System.out.println("Enter number:");
    double d = scanner.nextDouble();

    if (d > max) {
        max = d;
    }
    else if (d < min) {
        min = d;
    }
    total += d;
}

Double avg = total / n;
System.out.println("max: " + max + ", min: " + min + ", avg: " + avg);
```